# When does msg.sender change?

Tags: contract-development, msg.sender

If a function inside a contract calls another function in the same contract, is the msg.sender now the contract or still the original address that sent the initial transaction?

I know if contract A calls a function from contract B, the msg.sender is now contract A, but what about internally within 1 contract? does the msg.sender ever change? or is always the original tx sender?

Comment: it should stay the same, unless you are using this.functionName(..) to call that function.

Comment: to call an external function in your contract from your contract you need to use "this." and then it will change

Answer (score 1):

Internally the msg.sender stays the same so caller of the function.

Comment: unless a function with external modifier with ("this") is called